# Prove/Disprove the function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be an entire function prove/disprove the following:
>
> 1. if for all $z$,  $f(z)=f(iz)$ so $f$ is constant
> 2. if for all $z$,  $f(z)=f(3z)$ so $f$ is constant

So we need to use liouville theorem so we need to prove/disprove that the function is bounded.

I know that $sinz$ is not bounded in $\mathbb{C}$ but both functions seems to be bounded so the are constant ?

Comment: I think $z^4$ is a counter example for the first one.

Comment: You can show that the 2nd one is bounded, use the fact that $f(z)=f(z/3)$ in particular for every $k$ you have $f(z)=f(z/{3^k})$ so you are very close to f(0). Then use liouville theorem. If it's needed I will add the details.

Comment: @yanko why $z^4$ is not bounded?

Comment: Well if it is bot bounded as a real function then it is not bounded as a complex function (the converse is wrong, as you mentioned with sin(z))

Comment: f (z)=z^4 is definately a counter example.  (Iz)^4=i^4z^4=z^4.  But being unbounded proves it *isn't* a costant.  I don't understand your objection.  I think f

Comment: You don't have to prove it is unbounded (although it obviously is), you just have to prove it isn'isn't constant (which it obviously is not) and that f (z)=f (iz) which is easy.